# What duty should I expect to pay on a used iMac from USA to Kenya?

Tags: shipping, customs, kenya

I'm moving to Kenya in the next month, and I have an [enormous 27" iMac](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP718?locale=en_US). I want to take it with me (I'm a software developer), but I'm doubtful that I can fit it in my luggage, so I'm thinking of shipping it.

The shipping costs seem affordable (†), but Kenyan customs fees are a mystery to me. This is *not* a new iMac. Should I expect to pay duty or taxes on it? How much? Are my customs-associated risks higher if I ship it than if I check it as luggage?

† **Detail**: A site like [myus.com](https://www.myus.com/pricing) quotes me ~$200 to send it, which is cheaper than

Comment: hi, speaking from my own experience of shipping tech equipment to thailand, vietnam, jamaica, not being able to find information about it, and then being hit with 20-100% customs fees, i would avoid shipping separately if at all possible

Comment: Not exclusive to expats, this affects anyone travelling if you're taking it as luggage.  Either reword, or ask on travel.SE.

Comment: Travel isn't about people moving. If an expat who's moving, you take your 27" iMac with you. If you're just traveling, you don't.

The help center is a big place. Where exactly does it say that this question is out of scope?